# Angular 4 - Sort Column Table

Tags: angular

I have based on this example to sort the columns of a table:
[Sort Table Colums](https://plnkr.co/edit/nll91DbcDsWvGOQauHNx?p=preview)

This is the code pipe:

```
import {Pipe, PipeTransform} from 'angular2/core';

@Pipe({  name: 'orderBy' })
export class OrderrByPipe implements PipeTransform {

  transform(records: Array<any>, args?: any): any {

    return records.sort(function(a, b){
          if(a[args.property] < b[args.property]){
            return -1 * args.direction;
          }
          else if( a[args.property] > b[args.property]){
            return 1 * args.direction;
          }
          else{
            return 0;
          }
        });
    };
}
```

This is the html code:

```
<tr *ngFor="let particular of particulars | orderBy: {property: column, direction: direction} | slice:1; let i = index">
```

The import in the component:

```
import { OrderrByPipe } from '../pipes/orderby.pipe';
```

I want to migrate the pipe class to Angular 4, How could do it?

This is the error in console:

```
error_handler.js:60 Error: Uncaught (in promise): Error: Error in ./ParticularsListComponent class ParticularsListComponent - inline template:42:14 caused by: Cannot read property 'sort' of undefined
Error: Error in ./ParticularsListComponent class ParticularsListComponent - inline template:42:14 caused by: Cannot read property 'sort' of undefined
```

Comment: Your problem is that particulars is null (well `undefined` exactly). Could you check it please ?

Comment: That was the problem,thanks

Comment: no longer gives any error, but does not order

Comment: With only that code I can't help you. What are the values of direction and column ?

Comment: I just solved it, the parameter of the function was not fine, I have inserted a capital letter and it has to be the same as the object, everything ok

Comment: Nice, I'm making a comment so that you can mark your answer as resolved

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem comes from the `particulars` variable that is undefined.

Answer (score 0):

```
import { Pipe, PipeTransform } from '@angular/core';

@Pipe({
  name: 'orderby'
})
export class OrderbyPipe implements PipeTransform {


  //private records : Array<any> = [];

    transform(records :Array<Object>, args?: any): any {
    if(records != null){
      return records.sort(function(a, b){
            if (a[args.property] === '' || a[args.property] === null || typeof a[args.property] === 'undefined') {
            return 1 * args.direction;
            }
            if (b[args.property] === '' || b[args.property] === null || typeof b[args.property] === 'undefined') {
            return -1 * args.direction;
            }
          if(a[args.property] < b[args.property]){
            return -1 * args.direction;
          }
          else if( a[args.property] > b[args.property]){
            return 1 * args.direction;
          }
          else{
            return 0;
          }
        });
    }
    };

}
```

Comment: Please check this, it worked for me, but i see one thing in that, integer sorting suppose if we take 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13. it is behaving wierdly.